# Include only required modules in maven dependency

Tags: maven, jakarta-ee, maven-3, maven-plugin, maven-assembly-plugin

I have profiles defined as below in pom file of external dependency (jar). When I use it as a dependency in my project's pom file, I need to use only java/testmodule2 in it. Is it possible to write some plugin to exclude all the modules (including sql module) except java/testmodule2 ?

```
<profiles>
<profile>
  <id>java</id>
  <modules>
    <module>java/testmodule1</module>
    <module>java/testmodule2</module>
    <module>java/testmodule3</module>
  </modules>
</profile>
<profile>
  <id>database</id>
  <modules>
    <module>sql</module>
  </modules>
</profile>
```

Note: I can't make any changes in pom file of external dependency-jar as it is external library.

Comment: If these modules are all listed as dependencies of the dependency you do include, then you can just use the "excludes" mechanism built into Maven - see https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html

Comment: @moilejter the modules can keep growing and I might need to manually do the exclusion if any new module is added to external dependency.

Comment: I would think that's a feature - how would you know in principle whether you'd need the other module, otherwise?